# How to query 'or' conditions to RESTful API by query string parameters?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Many people say developers should use query string parameters if they are querying RESTful APIs with conditions.

I agree with them and I was peacefully implementing RESTful APIs using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in my [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) project, until I faced an situation where I had to query with *or* conditions, not *and* conditions which are supported by `&` character in query string.

If I want to query my recently modified log history of this week, for example, it will go something like:

```
my-site/api/log?created=-7,*&modified=-3,*
```

But since query string uses `&` for appending parameters, I can't find any elegant solution to filter my resources with *or* condition.

What I'm looking for is, like:

```
my-site/api/log?created=-1[OR]created=-2[OR] ...
```

So is there any nice, terse and restful way to add *or* condition to my query string?

Comment: what about `created=-1_-2_5` or `created=-1+-2+5` and then in python, replacing _ with OR and + with ANDs

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:
You can tune your `get_queryset()` for the api:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Override get_queryset() to filter on multiple values for 'created'
    """

    created = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('created', None)
    if created:
        created_list = created.split(',')
        if len(created_list)>1:
            queryset = yourmodel.objects.filter(created__in=created_list)
        elif len(created_list) == 1:
            queryset = yourmodel.objects.filter(created=created_list[0])

    return queryset
```

And request will be:
Single Request: `my-site/api/log?created=-7`
Multi request: `my-site/api/log?created=-7,6,1,2`

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the `kwarg`

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3')
>>> q.getlist('a')
[u'1', u'2', u'3']
>>> q.get('a')
u'3'
```

More about `QueryDict` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).